# asp.net razor pages webmatrix ajax post won't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor, webmatrix

So I'm just trying to post data to a page with ajax.. but it doesn't work.. any ideas?

```
                $.ajax({
                url: '/REST/GetResponse.cshtml',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    username: $('#username').val(),
                    firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
                    lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    password1: $('#password1').val(),
                    password2: $('#password2').val(),
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success " + result.UserName);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Failed");
                }

            });
        }
```

That is my ajax post -

```
@{
if (IsPost)
{
    var password = Request["password1"];
    var username = Request["username"];
}
```

}

That is the page where its being posted to but when I look at the console it says (cancelled) and the error functions pops the alert.

I appreciate your help :) thank you

Comment: It seems you're expecting POSTed key/value pairs (`Request["key"]`) vs. JSON.stringify (string representation of object `{"x":5,"y":6}`)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net Web Pages normally expect `POST` requests to be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than JSON. Just set the `contentType` to that (or don't set it at all, since that's the default) and get rid of the `JSON.stringify()` call. jQuery will automatically do the encoding for you.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is to serialize your form an submit it. If your form id is "userdata" your Ajax post should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/REST/GetResponse.cshtml',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: $("#userdata").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success " + result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed");
    }
};
```

and your /REST/GetResponse.cshtml file something like:

```
@{
    var password = Request["password1"];
    var username = Request["username"];
    // and so on ...

    try 
    {
        // do something...
        Response.Write(username);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Instead, if you want to retain your original Ajax post, I think that your /REST/GetResponse.cshtml should be:

```
@{
    string input;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
      input = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    var user = Json.Decode(input);
    var password = user.password1;
    var username = user.username;
    // and so on ...

    try 
    {
        // do something...
        Response.Write(username);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```